# I want to construct a list of nested dictionaries from 3 python lists where one of the 3 lists contains duplicates

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

I’m trying to construct a list of nested dictionaries and yes there are duplicate values in List_A.

Basically, for each outer key,  I’m trying to consolidate all of its inner key/value pairs

I wrote the following line of code:

```
A = ['sibsp', 'sibsp', 'pclass',    'pclass', 'pclass', 'age', 'age', 'age', 'age', 'age', 'age', 'fare', 'fare', 'fare', 'fare', 'fare', 'parch', 'parch'] 

B = ['(-0.001, 1.0]', '(1.0, 8.0]', '1', '2', '3', '(0.419, 19.0]', '(19.0, 25.0]', '(25.0, 31.8]', '(31.8, 41.0]', '(41.0, 80.0]', 'nan', '(-0.001, 7.854]', '(10.5, 21.679]', '(21.679, 39.688]', '(39.688, 512.329]', '(7.854, 10.5]', '(-0.001, 1.0]', '(1.0, 6.0]']

C = [-0.043281487422643504, 0.5199640685633579, -1.0039159555090957, -0.3644848445981264, 0.6664826567146916, -0.4000843004236305, 0.24183838283179523, -0.04150528802138758, -0.2219732761660194, 0.04505675173309271, 0.4037823142739484, 0.8047930720327325, -0.16862729546072658, -0.25014415313271576, -1.0575407967677335, 0.9062269696875864, 0.04021888607232296, -0.32565170564086077]


listOfNestedDicts=[ {i:{j:k}} for (i,j,k) in zip(List_A,List_B,List_C) ]
```

I got the following output which is a list of nested dictionaries but it is not what I want and it won’t work in my application since sibsb, pclass, age, fare, and parch are unique columns in a dataframe and I will be mapping the inner B keys to their corresponding C values

```
[{'sibsp': {'(-0.001, 1.0]': -0.043281487422643504}},
{'sibsp': {'(1.0, 8.0]': 0.5199640685633579}},
{'pclass': {'1': -1.0039159555090957}},
{'pclass': {'2': -0.3644848445981264}},
{'pclass': {'3': 0.6664826567146916}},
{'age': {'(0.419, 19.0]': -0.4000843004236305}},
{'age': {'(19.0, 25.0]': 0.24183838283179523}},
{'age': {'(25.0, 31.8]': -0.04150528802138758}},
{'age': {'(31.8, 41.0]': -0.2219732761660194}},
{'age': {'(41.0, 80.0]': 0.04505675173309271}},
{'age': {'nan': 0.4037823142739484}},
{'fare': {'(-0.001, 7.854]': 0.8047930720327325}},
{'fare': {'(10.5, 21.679]': -0.16862729546072658}},
{'fare': {'(21.679, 39.688]': -0.25014415313271576}},
{'fare': {'(39.688, 512.329]': -1.0575407967677335}},
{'fare': {'(7.854, 10.5]': 0.9062269696875864}},
{'parch': {'(-0.001, 1.0]': 0.04021888607232296}},
{'parch': {'(1.0, 6.0]': -0.32565170564086077}}]
```

The output that I would like to get is the following:

```
[{'sibsp': {'(-0.001, 1.0]': -0.043281487422643504,'(1.0, 8.0]': 0.5199640685633579}},
{'pclass': {'1': -1.0039159555090957 ,'2': -0.3644848445981264, '3': 0.6664826567146916}},
{'age': {'(0.419, 19.0]': -0.4000843004236305,'(19.0, 25.0]': 0.24183838283179523,'(25.0, 31.8]': -0.04150528802138758,'(31.8, 41.0]': -0.2219732761660194,'(41.0, 80.0]': 0.04505675173309271,'nan': 0.4037823142739484}},
{'fare': {'(-0.001, 7.854]': 0.8047930720327325,'(10.5, 21.679]': -0.16862729546072658, '(21.679, 39.688]': -0.25014415313271576,'(39.688, 512.329]': -1.0575407967677335,'(7.854, 10.5]': 0.9062269696875864}},
{'parch': {'(-0.001, 1.0]': 0.04021888607232296,'(1.0, 6.0]': -0.32565170564086077}}]
```

Comment: It would probably make more sense to create a dictionary than to create a list of single-key dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result using this code:

```
result = []
keys = list(set(A))
for key in keys:
    inner_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == key:
            inner_dict[B[i]] = C[i]
    result.append({key: inner_dict})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `pandas.DataFrame` anyways, you could also just go the route through pandas to achieve the desired result in a one-liner that combines list- and dict-comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
result = {key: [value2.to_dict() for key2, value2 in sub_df.iloc[:, 1:].iterrows()] for key, sub_df in pd.DataFrame([A, B, C], index=['a', 'b', 'c']).T.groupby('a')}
```

The idea: we group by column A in the `groupby`-statement and subsequently iterate over the rows of the sub-DataFrames and transform those into a dictionary.